# Бесконечный цикл WordPress (wp_doing_ajax)

Tags: php, wordpress

Дoбрый дeнь. Если использовать фильтр `wp_doing_ajax`, то он срабатывает и при вызове функции `wp_send_json_error()`, соответственно получается бесконечный цикл:

```
add_filter( 'wp_doing_ajax', 'call_ajax_test' );
function call_ajax_test( $wp_doing_ajax ) {
  wp_send_json_error();
  return $wp_doing_ajax;
}

wp_send_json('test'); // Делаем первый AJAX-запрос
```

Результат:

```
1) wp_send_json('test') -> wp_doing_ajax -> wp_send_json_error()
2) wp_doing_ajax -> wp_send_json_error()
3) wp_doing_ajax -> wp_send_json_error()
4) wp_doing_ajax -> wp_send_json_error()
5) ...
```

Вопрос: как вызвать `wp_send_json_error()` и избежать бесконечного цикла?

P.S. Вроде разобрался, но остался другой вопрос. Данный `add_filter` ожидает `return`, а `wp_send_json_success()` или `wp_send_json_error()` после своего выполнения обрывает работу при помощи `die()` и `return` не происходит :(

Comment: это происходи потому что вы вызываете фильтр одноименный с функцией которая и использует этот фильтр и эта функция вызывается в функции wp_send_json. я так понимаю вы хотите отключить wp ajax?

Comment: @DarthKYL благодарю за ответ! Хотел запретить все ajax вызовы, кроме избранного списка. Только есть проблемка... В целом всё работает ОК, но `add_filter` ожидает `return`, а `wp_send_json_success()` или `wp_send_json_error()` после своего выполнения обрывают работу при помощи `die()` и `return` не происходит :(

Comment: Тут типичная пролема XY. Вы чего хотите в результате - запретить любые ajax, кроме избранного списка? Так и задавайте вопрос, я на него отвечу. А здесь вы пытаетесь решить проблему, которую сами же создали неправильным подходом.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что истинная цель автора - другая.

Comment: @KAGGDesign здравствуйте. Я оформил новый вопрос, буду благодарен, если Вы посмотрите на него: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1254803/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-ajax-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5-wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтоб не было зацикливания вам нужно удалить ваш фильтр перед вызовом wp_send_json

```
add_filter( 'wp_doing_ajax', 'call_ajax_test' );

function call_ajax_test( $wp_doing_ajax ) {
    remove_filter( 'wp_doing_ajax', 'call_ajax_test' );

    wp_send_json_success();

    add_filter( 'wp_doing_ajax', 'call_ajax_test' );

    return $wp_doing_ajax;
}

wp_send_json('test');
```