# Отклонять все AJAX запросы, кроме... (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Дoбрый дeнь. Возникла необходимость отклонять все AJAX запросы к `admin-ajax.php`, если они исходят не от администратора или формы обратной связи. Данный код работает, но возник вопрос - может ли WordPress самостоятельно инициировать обращения к `admin-ajax.php` (как он это делает с `wp-cron.php`)? Если да, то каким образом можно внести его в исключения?

```
add_action('admin_init', 'my_ajax_checker', 10, 2);

function my_ajax_checker() {

  // Делаем исключение для формы обратной связи
  $send_form = $_POST['action'] === 'elementor_pro_forms_send_form';

  // Отклонять все AJAX запросы, кроме администратора и формы обратной связи
  if( defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX && !current_user_can('manage_options') && !$send_form) {
    $response = array( 'message' => 'Error', 'data' => array (), );
    wp_send_json_error( $response );
    }
}
```

Comment: у ajax не такого понятия, как "запрос от wordpress". Хороший программист сможет эмулировать запросы якобы от wordpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не посмотрев тольком код в вопросе и памятую проблему в предыдущем, я написал такой код:

```
/**
 * Whitelist ajax calls.
 *
 * @param string $tag    The name of the action to be executed.
 * @param mixed  ...$arg Optional. Additional arguments which are passed on to the
 *                       functions hooked to the action. Default empty.
 */
function whitelist_ajax( $tag, ...$arg ) {
    if ( 0 !== strpos( $tag, 'wp_ajax_' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $whitelist = [
        'elementor_pro_forms_send_form',
    ];

    $action = preg_replace( '/(?:wp_ajax_|wp_ajax_nopriv_)(.+)/', '$1', $tag );
    if ( in_array( $action, $whitelist, true ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $response = new WP_Error( '', 'Ajax request blocked' );

    wp_send_json_error( $response );
}

add_action( 'all', 'whitelist_ajax' );
```

Он протестирован и работает.

Но по сути, ваш код и код в ответе практически идентичны по функционалу за тем исключением, что мой код срабатывает позднее и позволяет WordPress ответить 400, если действие (action) не зарегистрировано.

Comment: большое спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Скажите, пожалуйста, может ли кто-нибудь кроме клиента (администратора или посетителя) инициировать AJAX-запросы к `admin-ajax.php`? Т.е. может ли возникнуть ситуация, что будет заблокирован легитимный AJAX-запрос? Гипотетический пример: запускается `wp-cron.php` -> WordPress инициирует AJAX-запрос, он не проходит проверку т.к. `!current_user_can('manage_options') === true` - или это фантастика?

Comment: Запросы может инициировать кто угодно, с любого сайта. Но WordPress имеет систему защиты от "чужих" запросов, называется она nonce.